# Pyspark: Convert column to lowercase

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert the values inside a column to lowercase. Currently if I use the `lower()` method, it complains that column objects are not callable. Since there's a function called `lower()` in SQL, I assume there's a native Spark solution that doesn't involve UDFs, or writing any SQL.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Import `lower` alongside `col`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, col
```

Combine them together using `lower(col("bla"))`. In a complete query:

```
spark.table('bla').select(lower(col('bla')).alias('bla'))
```

which is equivalent to the SQL query

```
SELECT lower(bla) AS bla FROM bla
```

To keep the other columns, do

```
spark.table('foo').withColumn('bar', lower(col('bar')))
```

Needless to say, this approach is better than using a UDF because UDFs have to call out to Python (which is a slow operation, and Python itself is slow), and is more elegant than writing it in SQL.

Answer (score 7):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower

df = df.withColumn("col_name", lower(df["col_name"]))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of concat_ws and split

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('arr_str', lower(concat_ws('::','arr'))).withColumn('arr', split('arr_str','::')).drop('arr_str')
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach which may be a little cleaner:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select("*", F.lower("my_col"))
```

this returns a data frame with all the original columns, plus lowercasing the column which needs it.