# Convert column to lowercase with PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lowercase

I want to convert all the values to lower cases in the column "Channel". I have `df` that I created with PySpark in jupyter notebook. I have tried the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179745/pyspark-convert-column-to-lowercase) but got an error. So it is not a duplicate.

My data looks like this:

```
id     Channel     Brand
123    Hair        Fashion
124    Nails       Fashion
```

And I want it to be the following:

```
id     Channel     Brand
123    hair        Fashion
124    nails       Fashion
```

I have tried the following:

```
new_df = df.select(lower(df.Channel)).alias('Channel')
```

Which converts the values to lower cases but I am losing my other columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can do:

```
new_df = df.withColumn('Channel', lower(df.Channel))
```

This will preserve other columns as well.